# Arguments passed on the stack aren't being passed to the called function

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I am writing a game in x86-64 assembly for windows using nasm, cl.exe and the win32 API calls. My application succeeds in creating a window but it doesn't have the right size and positioning (it's very tall but narrow horizontally).

Here is the part of my code that creates the window and shows it after having obtained the `HINSTANCE` with `GetModuleHandleA(NULL)` and having registered the window class with `RegisterClassA`.

```
; Create The Window
mov RCX, 0               ; dwExStyle
mov RDX, WindowClassName ; lpClassName
MOV R8,  WindowName      ; lpWindowName
MOV R9,  13565952        ; dwStyle

sub rsp, 48
mov qword[rbp - 48], 0    ; lpParam
mov RAX, qword[HINSTANCE] ; 
mov qword[rbp - 40], RAX  ; hInstance
mov qword[rbp - 32], 0    ; hMenu
mov qword[rbp - 24], 0    ; hWndParent
mov dword[rbp - 16], 1080 ; nHeight
mov dword[rbp - 12], 1920 ; nWidth
mov dword[rbp - 8],  100  ; Y
mov dword[rbp - 4],  100  ; X
call CreateWindowExA
mov qword[HWND], RAX      ; Save the window handle

; Show The Window
mov RCX, qword[HWND]
mov RDX, 5                ; SW_SHOW
call ShowWindow
```

I took a look at it in binary ninja and I shows me that only the 6 first parameters are being passed to `CreateWindowExA`. I have looked at [Microsoft's x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160) but I don't see anything wrong.

The arguments are being passed like this according to it:
`CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle: 0, lpClassName: 0x403010, lpWindowName: 0x403023, dwStyle: 0xcf0000, X: 0x438, Y: 0x64)`. I do notice that X's value is wrong but I don't understand why either.

Thanks in advance for any help you might give me!

Here is my full code if it helps:

```
    global _start

    extern GetModuleHandleA
    extern RegisterClassA
    extern DefWindowProcA
    extern CreateWindowExA
    extern ShowWindow
    extern PeekMessageA
    extern TranslateMessage
    extern DispatchMessageA

    section .text

_start:
    ; Prologue
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp

    ; Get hInstance
    xor  RCX, RCX
    call GetModuleHandleA
    mov qword[HINSTANCE], RAX ; Save hInstance

    ; Register The Window Class
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA], 3                    ; style
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 8], DefWindowProcA   ; lpfnWndProc
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA + 12], 0               ; cbClsExtra
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA + 16], 0               ; cbWndExtra
    mov RAX, qword[HINSTANCE]
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 24], RAX             ; hInstance
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 32], 0               ; hIcon
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 40], 0               ; hCursor
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 48], 0               ; hbrBackground
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 56], 0               ; lpszMenuName
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 64], WindowClassName ; lpszClassName

    lea  RCX, WNDCLASSA
    call RegisterClassA

    ; Create The Window
    mov RCX, 0               ; dwExStyle
    mov RDX, WindowClassName ; lpClassName
    MOV R8,  WindowName      ; lpWindowName
    MOV R9,  13565952        ; dwStyle

    sub rsp, 48
    mov qword[rbp - 48], 0    ; lpParam
    mov RAX, qword[HINSTANCE] ; 
    mov qword[rbp - 40], RAX  ; hInstance
    mov qword[rbp - 32], 0    ; hMenu
    mov qword[rbp - 24], 0    ; hWndParent
    mov dword[rbp - 16], 1080 ; nHeight
    mov dword[rbp - 12], 1920 ; nWidth
    mov dword[rbp - 8],  100  ; Y
    mov dword[rbp - 4],  100  ; X
    call CreateWindowExA
    mov qword[HWND], RAX      ; Save the window handle

    ; Show The Window
    mov RCX, qword[HWND]
    mov RDX, 5
    call ShowWindow

a:
    jmp a

; Message Loop
message_loop:
    LEA RCX, MSG
    mov RDX, qword[HWND]
    mov R8, 0
    mov R9, 0
    sub rsp, 4
    mov dword[rbp - 4], 1
    call PeekMessageA

    LEA RCX, MSG
    call TranslateMessage

    LEA RCX, MSG
    call DispatchMessageA

    jmp message_loop

; Epilogue
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret

    section .data

HINSTANCE       dq 0
HWND            dq 0 
WindowClassName db 'Polar Window Class', 0
WindowName      db 'Polar Window',       0

    section .bss

WNDCLASSA resb 72
MSG       resb 48
```

Comment: `sub rsp, 48` is suspicious. You have 12 arguments, I'd expect that to be 12*8=96. The extra arguments should be put on the stack starting from `[rsp+32]`. Note stack slots are 8 bytes, even if you pass 4 byte integers.

Comment: @Jester What do you mean by a stack slot? Should all the arguments be 8 byte aligned? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can consult a compiler if you like.

Comment: @Jester Thank you. I think I understand it now. I added shadow space and aligned all my stack parameters to 8 bytes and it seems to work now. Can you just confirm that the shadow space must be "allocated" after the stack parameters?

Comment: Jester is correct, the shadow space is the first 32 bytes on the stack just prior to a function call and the parameters are after that.

Comment: The shadow space is the area where you would normally put the first 4 arguments. The callee may copy them there.

Comment: You also need to declare unwind codes so that exception handling will work. Unwind codes will be easier to write if you do your stack pointer adjustment in the prologue, to avoid the hassle of having to declare shrink-wrapping.

Comment: Why assembly, though? Performance doesn't appear to be an immediate goal with all those conversions between ANSI and UTF-16.

Comment: @IInspectable I am writing it in assembly to learn it because I find it interesting as I come from a C++ background. My issue has been resolved thanks to all of you. Does anyone want to write an answer or shall I?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there have been previous questions where Windows x64 shadow space was the answer.  Probably one of those involved passing stack args in the wrong place, but IDK.  (Not allocating shadow space at all is a more common problem; most functions don't have many args).  But anyway, there's likely a duplicate, so we should look for one first before writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code had many issues so I couldn't find a question where they were all addressed. As a result, here is how I fixed my problem with the help of the comments (thank you). I was not allocating shadow space and I did not align the parameters I put on the stack to 8 bytes. My assembly code now looks like this (**not optimized and without exception handling**):

```
    global _start

    extern GetModuleHandleA
    extern RegisterClassA
    extern DefWindowProcA
    extern CreateWindowExA
    extern ShowWindow
    extern PeekMessageA
    extern TranslateMessage
    extern DispatchMessageA

    section .text

_start:
    ; Prologue
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp

    ; Get hInstance
    xor  RCX, RCX

    call GetModuleHandleA
    
    mov qword[HINSTANCE], RAX ; Save hInstance

    ; Register The Window Class
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA], 3                    ; style
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 8], DefWindowProcA   ; lpfnWndProc
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA + 12], 0               ; cbClsExtra
    mov dword[WNDCLASSA + 16], 0               ; cbWndExtra
    mov RAX, qword[HINSTANCE]
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 24], RAX             ; hInstance
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 32], 0               ; hIcon
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 40], 0               ; hCursor
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 48], 0               ; hbrBackground
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 56], 0               ; lpszMenuName
    mov qword[WNDCLASSA + 64], WindowClassName ; lpszClassName

    lea  RCX, WNDCLASSA
    sub  rsp, 0x20 ; Shadow Space
    call RegisterClassA
    add  rsp, 0x20 ; Shadow Space

    ; Create The Window
    xor RCX, RCX             ; dwExStyle
    mov RDX, WindowClassName ; lpClassName
    MOV R8,  WindowName      ; lpWindowName
    MOV R9,  13565952        ; dwStyle

    sub rsp, 96

    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 56], 0    ; lpParam
    mov RAX, qword[HINSTANCE] ; 
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 48], RAX  ; hInstance
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 40], 0    ; hMenu
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 32], 0    ; hWndParent
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 24], 1080 ; nHeight
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 16], 1920 ; nWidth
    mov qword[rsp + 20h + 8],  100  ; Y
    mov qword[rsp + 20h],      100  ; X

    call CreateWindowExA

    add rsp, 96

    mov qword[HWND], RAX ; Save the window handle

    ; Show The Window
    sub rsp, 0x20

    mov RCX, qword[HWND]
    mov RDX, 5
    call ShowWindow

    add rsp, 0x20

; Message Loop
message_loop:
    sub rsp, 48

    LEA RCX, [MSG]
    mov RDX, qword[HWND]
    mov R8, 0
    mov R9, 0
    mov qword[rsp + 20h], 1
    call PeekMessageA

    add rsp, 48

    sub rsp, 32

    LEA RCX, [MSG]
    call TranslateMessage

    LEA RCX, [MSG]
    call DispatchMessageA

    add rsp, 32

    jmp message_loop

    ; Epilogue
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

    section .data

HINSTANCE       dq 0
HWND            dq 0 
WindowClassName db 'Polar Window Class', 0
WindowName      db 'Polar Window',       0

    section .bss

WNDCLASSA resb 72
MSG       resb 48
```

Comment: Still not quite right. You didn't allocate shadow space when calling GetModuleHandleA, and you didn't declare any unwind codes.